# Enter text in input in Watir with same class

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, watir

I am trying to enter text into an input field and can not successfully get it working. I have two inputs that look like this:

```
<div class"outerParentClass">
    <div class="classLabel">From</div>
        <div class="classA classB classD">
            <div class="classE">
               <div class="classText"> TEXT HERE </div>
               <input class="classInputA classInoutB" type="text">
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="classLabel">To</div>
        <div class="classA classB classD">
            <div class="classE">
               <div class="classText"> DIFFERENT TEXT HERE </div>
               <input class="classInputA classInoutB" type="text">
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Both the inputs are the exact same format as above. There are no Id's and both have the same classes. I am struggling at entering the text into these or even finding them correctly.

When I do this:

```
browser.text_field(:class => "classInputA").size
```

It returns 20

When I do this:

```
browser.text_field(:class => "classInputA")
```

It returns:

```
#<Watir::TextField:0x..fbccafb7ed2e9b85e located=false selector={:class=>"classInputA", :tag_name=>"input"}>
```

Not sure how to locate either of these inputs. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text adjacent to the field provides a label and context for the field. As it is likely unique, you can use this to identify the element.

To do this, find the `div` containing the label text. Then navigate to the adjacent `div` that contains the text field.

```
browser.div(text: 'From', class: 'classLabel') # label of interest
  .element(xpath: './following-sibling::div[1]') # adjacent div containing text field
  .text_field # the text field
```

Note that in the next release of Watir, `.element(xpath: './following-sibling::div[1]')` will be replaceable by just `.following-sibling`.

Comment: The TEXT HERE is the text that displays in the input box. Therefore it is tough to search because the text may be different each time

Comment: Does that mean the `classText` is enabling `contenteditable` and the actual text field is not visible? As that is not a label, how do users know what the field is for? As a person, you can see which of these fields you want to interact with. At a minimum, you should be able to use those same rules for Watir.

Comment: Just edited the HTML to represent how it looks. I can find the parent class for the segment but am unable to get to the text fields.

Comment: @user081608 hi, You can use xpath in this case!

Comment: I updated how the text field can be located for the updated HTML. However, if the text field is not visible, you will not be able to use the `set` method.

Comment: I am able to find the div that is adjacent with it but I can't find the input. It says not exists for that one

Comment: Does the error say does not exist or is not present?